# pass transformed numpy arrays as reference

Tags: python, numpy

this may be something that isn't supposed to work the way I imagine it:
I would like a variable that is a numpy transformation of another array and that will automatically reflect changes to the other array.

I don't understand at what point numpy arrays stop being passed as a reference rather than value

A simple example where arrays are passed as reference:

```
import numpy as np


a=np.arange(5)
print 'a original', a
b=a
print 'b = a', b
a[0]=10
print 'a modified', a
print 'b ', b
```

however, as soon as I apply any transformation to b, the reference to a is lost.

```
import numpy as np
a=np.arange(5)
print 'a original', a
b=np.diff(a)
print 'b = np.diff(a)', b
a[0]=10

print 'a modified', a
print 'b ', b
```

I am looking for a way to maintain the reference from b to a in this second example.

I thought about writing a wrapper class like this:

```
import numpy as np
class linkedVariables:
    def __init__(self,a=np.arange(5)):
        self.a=a
        self.b=np.diff(self.a)

    def c(self):
        return np.diff(self.a)

lv=linkedVariables()

print 'a original', lv.a
print 'b = np.diff(a)', lv.b
print 'c = np.diff(a)', lv.c()
lv.a[0]=10

print 'a modified', lv.a
print 'b ', lv.b
print 'c ', lv.c()
```

Now lv.c() maintains the reference to a of course but I would rather have a solution that is 'invisible' to the outside of the class linkedVariables in the sense that I want to be able to call lv.c rather than lv.c()

Is that possible?

(or any other solution that doesn't require the new class at all?)

Comment: "I would like a variable that is a numpy transformation of another array and that will automatically reflect changes to the other array" - not going to happen, and most ways of achieving a similar effect have a lot of overhead.

Comment: @user2357112 why is that? Is this by (python) design? what ways of achieving a similar effect are there? If most have overhead, are there some that don't?